# Android Layout problem

Tags: android, android-layout

Hey, I tried to designed my layout to be like below picture, but I don't know how 
so, could you guys help me to redesign it or give me some correction

looking forward to hearing from you guys , Thanks for advance

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="320dip">
<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/pic"
    android:id="@+id/picture">
</ImageView>
</LinearLayout>

<TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchColumns="*">
    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
            <SeekBar android:id="@+id/seekbar" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:progress="3" 
            android:max="25"
            android:maxWidth="100px" 
            android:paddingRight="25px">
            </SeekBar>

            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/tx_color"
            android:text="None">
            </TextView>     

 </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioGroup android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/QueGroup1">
            <RadioButton android:checked="true"
            android:id="@+id/simple_mode" android:text="Default"/>
            <RadioButton android:checked="false"
            android:id="@+id/warn_mode" android:text="Warning"/>
            <RadioButton android:checked="false"
            android:id="@+id/grey_mode" android:text="Grey Scale"/>

            </RadioGroup>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

---

|
|
|                   ImageView
|
|
|
|
|***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**
|    Spinner                   | TextView
|
|**__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**
|  3 of radio buttons 
|***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**
 sorry about this b/c I cant post an image T^T

Comment: from your layout xml it seems you want an Image in first row, a seekbar and textview in second row and a radio group in the third. Is that correct beacuse your drawing doesn't confer to this

Answer (score 3):

It really depends what you want it to look like (the ascii graphics didn't help much there :) )

For one thing, your layout should have a single topmost container.. so you can do something like this (meta layout):

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
  <ImageView />
  <TableLayout>
    <TableRow>
      <SeekBar /> <!-- row 1 col 1 -->
      <TextView /> <!-- row 1 col 2 -->
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
      <TextView /> <!-- row 2 col 1, if you need an empty column, just leave the text empty -->
      <RadioGroup /> <!-- row 2 col 2 -->
    </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Is that something like what you need?

It will generate something like this:
[image: Android Layout]

**UPD:** You said that you wanted the radio group to be a single wide column.. In this case you just put it outside the table, same as the `ImageView`
If this example is your whole layout (i.e. you don't have any other rows with seekBar/textViews, then you can remove the `TableLayout` completely:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
  <ImageView />
  <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal">
    <SeekBar />
    <TextView />
  </LinearLayout>
  <RadioGroup />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yeah , it is much like I think but for the bottom row can I merge it for RadioGroup into single row?   thanks a lot for your support :))

Comment: Sure.. if you want to merge the bottom row, you just put it outside the table row

Comment: Just added another example.. If you just have these 4 elements on your screen - you don't need the `TableLayout` at all :) Hope this helps

Comment: Don't forget to approve the answer (the big tick icon next to my answer) if it is the right one :)

Comment: Oh, thank you very much Artiom Chilaru but I can't tick because it's need a reputation T-T. However, Its really u

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need reputation to accept an answer (the tick is below the upvote and downvote buttons) :)